# zipping a folder via PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, zip

I have a folder with the structure: `/home/test/test123`

Inside this I have another `BlobFi` named directory with jpg images and in `test123` I have a txt file. I want to zip the contents of `test123` that is `BlobFi` and the txt file into one folder.

Is there any PL/SQL method which can compress this `test123` to `test123.zip` ?

I Tried referring to [THIS](https://technology.amis.nl/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/as_zip8.txt) but dont know how will I use it for my condition.

Comment: And what the problem ? In you referense exists some examples  `as_zip.add1file( g_zipped_blob, 'dir3/', null ); -- a folder` are you try it?

Comment: Maybe good thing would be consider of another method for this i.e.: create batch script which will zip the files using 7zip and manage it's execution from dbms job level? It's just a hint of course :)